# Accessory view not attached to the keyboard on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, inputaccessoryview

I'm adding an accessory view with a "done" button on a keyboard.

I'm using this code:

```
        let toolbar2 = UIToolbar()
        toolbar2.sizeToFit()

        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Aceptar", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressedPicker))
        let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        toolbar2.setItems([flexibleSpace, doneButton], animated: false)

        alimentosText.inputAccessoryView = toolbar2
        alimentosText.inputView = picker
```

It works fine in the simulator with all devices. I also use it on my iPhone and works fine, but when I test it on a real iPad, the accessory view, shows exactly in the middle of the screen, not over the keyboard. How can I correct this?

This is how it looks on iPad simulator:

[image]

This is how it looks on iPhone (real device):

[image]

And this is the problem running on real iPad:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are you running some other layout code? I just tried a quick test, and it's working fine on a physical iPad...

Comment: I'm learning to code so I'm not sure what is another layout code, but can it be because this keyboard appears to enter text in a popUp View? @DonMag

Comment: How are you showing your "green" view with the fields? Are you presenting another ViewController? Or is that a subview added to the "main" view?

Comment: @DonMag thanks for your answer; I guess it's a subview, I use this code:        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your approach... Try creating a new project, and use this as your ViewController (you don't have to add anything in Storyboard): https://pastebin.com/gsdfxftK ... If that still puts the Toolbar at the top of the screen, then it seems something weird is going on with your device.

Comment: I tried with a new project and the same problem.. but in another iPad it was working perfect, not sure what's wrong with mine. Thanks a lot! @DonMag